# Upgrading From Create-React-App to Next.js - Nothing is showing up

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have developed a Next.js server-side rendering application. I need to use something like [this](https://github.com/mineshkothari/react-timeline-florin-pop) client-side rendering react app that creates a timeline.

**Steps that I took to use it with my application**:

I just copied src folder content to the "pages" folder of my own application.

In routes.js file of my application, I gave the navigation to App.js.

**In order to use CSS with Next.js**(according to [this](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/299) link):

I imported Head from Next and added a link to the CSS file.

So, the file(App.js) looks like this now:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import Timeline from './components/Timeline';
 import Head from 'next/head';

 class App extends Component {

   state = {
    timelineData: [
    {
      text: 'Wrote my first blog post ever on Medium',
      date: 'March 03 2017',
      category: {
        tag: 'medium',
        color: '#018f69'
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'This is the second timeline item',
    date: 'September 22 2017',
    category: {
        tag: 'tag-two',
        color: '#018f69'
     }
   }
 ]
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Head>
       <link href="/App.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </Head>
      <Timeline data={this.state.timelineData} />
    </div>
 );
 }
}

export default App;
```

However, now when I go to the page nothing is showing up and there is no error.

Can somebody tell me how I can solve the problem?

Comment: What if you remove css file next.js referrs too, once again, does the react app show something?

Comment: Is the path to /statics/App.css correct? Foldername? Filename? Have you tried with ./?

Comment: Where is the location of your pages statics folder?

Comment: I removed the static folder and placed the .css file in the "pages" folder and in the head tag gave the path like this: `<link href="./App.css" rel="stylesheet" />`. But the problem still remains. I believe the paths are correct.

Comment: Do you think everything else is fine? Did I do the migration properly?

Comment: File looks good as far as I can see, but I have no clue if you did the migration properly ... not enough information ....

Comment: Please include the error message.